# Method for doing stuff before closing an aplication?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4

Is there any way to perform something before the application closes?
For example,someone closes the application, but before it happened I had to send some data to the server...

Comment: Are you talking about a browser based application?  Or an Adobe AIR Application?  OR a mobile application?

Comment: I don't see any reason why it should have been down voted, he's asking a legit question - maybe like me - he doesn't even realize that this has to be platform specific. Or better yet is there an agnostic way of doing this that we're all used to doing in Flex/AIR.

Comment: Its a browser based application...

Answer (score 2):

please clarify for which plattform!!!

For the Browser you will have to work with JavaScript onbeforeunload event and Flash externalInterface. [Here is a how to Link!](http://sierakowski.eu/list-of-tips/74-flash-detecting-browser-window-close.html)

For android it would look something like this!

```
if(Capabilities.cpuArchitecture=="ARM") // check if Android
{
    NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(Event.ACTIVATE, handleActivate, false, 0, true);
    NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(Event.DEACTIVATE, handleDeactivate, false, 0, true);
    NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, handleKeys, false, 0, true);
}

private function handleActivate(event:Event):void
{
    // load your stuff again or whatever 
    NativeApplication.nativeApplication.systemIdleMode = SystemIdleMode.KEEP_AWAKE;
}

private function handleDeactivate(event:Event):void
{
    // Save your Stuff and do whatever!!!
    NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit();
}

private function handleKeys(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.BACK){
        // Save your Stuff and do whatever!!!
        NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: I was just about to type an answer like this, but also include the solution for a web app: use the browser's `onbeforeunload` event. The OP can google for that, it's well documented. It has some shortcomings (also well documented), but is the only option in browsers. NativeApplication also dispatches Event.SUSPEND, any clue on what the difference is between SUSPEND and DEACTIVATE in terms of a mobile AIR app?

Comment: Not sure atm, id have to look it up aswell ;) But i think that was IOS only